# Scrollview vs Recyclerview vs Viewpager vs Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have a big content page but without any identifiable pattern and I have some different ways to implement it. Which is the best performance-wise?

-Recyclerview, even though we do not gain anything from recycling?
-Scrollview with fragments? (The purpose of using fragments is to separate the logic to smaller pieces)
-Horizontal view pager? (I think in that case we can not scroll smoothly...)
-Coordinator layout to scroll fragments?

Answer (score 0):

don't use viewpager, some problems may occur. Use recyclerview with pagerSnapHelper instead.

if you not need to recycler views, you can use horizontalscrollview with some views. Logic can be splitted into several classes, no fragment using needed. something like this:

```java
void onViewCreated(){
  View view = ...;
  helperView1.init(view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
  helperView2.init(view.findViewById(R.id.view2);
  helperView3.init(view.findViewById(R.id.view3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lot of content which is not per-determined, you are best off using RecyclerView. RecyclerView lets you easily load the data and handles the scrolling on its own. Even if there is nothing to be recycled, its best to use RecyclerView for a list of content. You can in fact use it with ConstraintLayout (or maybe fragments) if that's the best for your layouts.

Using any other layout directly for a large amount of content is not recommended. Handling multiple fragments without a proper adapter could be difficult. RecyclerView allows you to do that easily. Performance wise, ConstraintLayout is your best bet.